# C# and Minecraft server launch

Tags: c#, minecraft

Hey everyone I'm having trouble figuring out if it's possible to have a Minecraft server run in C#. when running the below code it batch file it launches cmd and starts the server normally.

```
java -Xmx1G -jar spigot-1.17.1.jar -nogui
```

The problem is I want to run it in C# for a future project

what code/if possible would make this run cause I've tried a few bit's of code similar to this with no success java version is JDK 17.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Cmd
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
ProcessStartInfo processToRunInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processToRunInfo.Arguments = ("java -Xmx1G -jar spigot-1.17.1.jar");
processToRunInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processToRunInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\DD\Desktop\Offical MC\Shopping District\";
processToRunInfo.FileName = "BuildTools.jar";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processToRunInfo;
    
}
```

Comment: java -Xmx1G -jar spigot-1.17.1.jar -nogui 
was run in a batch file not C#

Comment: In addition to jason's anwer: currently you're just creating a new `Process` object, but you also need to `Start` it (and possibly wait for it to exit).

Comment: ahhhhh I see *face palm*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the filename of the process to "java.exe", as this is the main process to be run.  The rest remain as arguments

```
processToRunInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
processToRunInfo.Arguments = ("-Xmx1G -jar spigot-1.17.1.jar");
```

You may also have to specify the full path to java.exe.

Comment: I changed these 2 but no success it returns error 0 in debug

 processToRunInfo.Arguments = ("-Xmx1G -jar spigot-1.17.1.jar");
 processToRunInfo.FileName = @"‪C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe";

Comment: Error Code 0 = Success

Comment: ahh okay cause there is no cmd promt where normally it gives you a ton of info/stay open as it appears to open then close if the code is correct cause the Minecraft server isn't showing. normally the batch file will open buildtools.jar create files etc